# How do I detect nul (0x00) characters in a vim string or register?

Tags: vim, regex, string, register

I have a vim register that contains a string. I need to step through each character in the string, and process each one individually.

My problem is that given a character pulled from the string, I am unable to tell the difference between a nul `0x00` character and a newline `0x0a`.

Because the register is specified by v:register, I cannot (as far as I know) access the register directly in a script in a way that would allow me to index into it (I'd be very happy to be corrected) and so I have to first copy/ref the register with `let l:string = getreg(v:register)` and then operate on `l:string`.

I have tried the following;-

1. `char2nr(l:string[x])` - always returns a nul character as `0x0a`
2. `match(l:string[x], '[\x0]')` - Matches `0x00` and `0x0a` characters!
3. `match(l:string[x], '\%x00')` - Matches `0x00` and `0x0a` characters!
   (though I would swear that this actually worked for me at one point - maybe I'm losing the plot?)
4. I have even tried pasting the character to a buffer with the hope of
   using the `g8` mapping to read back its value (ie, `exe "normal! r".l:string[x]."\<esc>"`) but it pasted a newline `0x0a`
5. A couple of other things which frankly I've forgotten now

Does anyone have any idea how I may accomplish this? The frustrating thing is vim handles nul characters perfectly fine when they appear in a  buffer (and it can visually select and yank them, and paste them again with no issues). But trying to deal with nul contained in a string or register seems to be broken.

Just for some background, the docs for `char2nr()` states that

*"NUL character in the file is specified with `nr2char(10)`, because NULs are represented with newline characters.  `nr2char(0)` is a real NUL and terminates the string, thus results in an empty string"*

This seems to be somewhat inaccurate (or not the whole story) because nul chars in a file/buffer are handled correctly. And a register that contains a nul can still be pasted into a document and it's correctly pasted as nul. So SOMETHING is making the distinction between nul and newline

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In many programming languages, a null character/byte is used to terminate a sting. Hence a (null-terminated) sting cannot possibly contain embedded null characters (since the very first null would be treated as the end of the string). You would need to use a byte or character array (rather than a string construct) to process null characters within text.  BTW the ASCII mnemonic for the null character is `NUL`; otherwise "null" is spelled with two 'l's.

Comment: Why do you even have `NUL`s embedded in your text strings? Perhaps you can preprocess the file with a binary (aka hex) editor, and replace each `NUL` with some other ASCII control character?

Comment: @sawdust - I know, but that's an implementation detail and not something I would expect to be exposed to the user of an editor (at least I wouldn't do that!). But my point remains that SOME parts of vim handle nul (NUL :-)) characters with no issues

Comment: @sawdust - I have written a hex editor in vim, using the xxd utility. I have managed to get around all of vim's other 'issues' regarding how it handles NUL and newlines. This one issue is proving to be rather awkward though. I CAN get around it but it will be a lot more work and not as efficient

Comment: @Peregrino69 - Sorry about that. Point noted